# How to use named routes and Rails path prefixes when a view is in a subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a document called 'letter_1.html' stored in 'static_pages/letters/letter_1.html', how do I correctly do routing and use named path notation to link?

Below is my code in routes.rb:

```
match '/letters/letter_1', to: 'static_pages/letters#letter_1', via: 'get'
```

If I want to call it I tried the following:

```
<%= link_to "Letter", letter_1_path %>
```

My guess is that 'letter_1_path' is the problem because of the two underlines. But what is the correct syntax to fix it? Also, I'm not sure if routing is done correctly with the subfolder. 
Thanks!

Comment: do `rake routes` in console and see all of your routes and use the proper one. and use `as: :letter_1` option for changing the url

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually name the route:

```
match '/letters/letter_1', to: 'static_pages/letters#letter_1', via: 'get', 
                           as: :letter_1
```

Then you can use `letter_1_path` and `letter_1_url`

There is also the rails 4 way:

```
namespace :static_pages do
  resources :letters, only: [] do
    collection do
      get :letter_1
    end
  end
end
```

Which will give you `letter_1_static_pages_letters`.

Checkout the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: A better approach would be to make a `letters#show` action, use the standard `resources :letters, only: [:show]`, pass `letter_1` as id, and then render the right template from the id, or throw a 404 if template doesn't exist.